# Install perf failed util/annotate.c: too few arguments to function 'init_disassemble_info

Tags: linux-kernel, perf

I compiled a 5.15.0 kernel, but the installation of `perf` failed.

I cannot download through `apt install`

```
WARNING: perf not found for kernel 5.15.0

  You may need to install the following packages for this specific kernel:
    linux-tools-5.15.0-5.15.0
    linux-cloud-tools-5.15.0-5.15.0

  You may also want to install one of the following packages to keep up to date:
    linux-tools-5.15.0
    linux-cloud-tools-5.15.0
```

Because：

```
E: Unable to locate software packages linux-tools-5.15.0-5.15.0
E: Unable to find any software packages according to global 'Linux tools 5.15.0-5.15.0'
E: Unable to find any software packages according to regular expressions linux-tools-5.15.0-5.15.0
```

So I compiled it through source code, but I got the following error message：

```
util/annotate.c: In function ‘symbol__disassemble_bpf’:
util/annotate.c:1739:2: error: too few arguments to function ‘init_disassemble_info’
  init_disassemble_info(&info, s,
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from util/annotate.c:1692:0:
/usr/local/include/dis-asm.h:480:13: note: declared here
 extern void init_disassemble_info (struct disassemble_info *dinfo, void *stream,
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  CC      arch/x86/util/pmu.o
  CC      util/block-range.o
  CC      ui/util.o
  CC      bench/futex-wake-parallel.o
/home/yi/perf-5.15.0/tools/build/Makefile.build:96: recipe for target 'util/annotate.o' failed
make[4]: *** [util/annotate.o] Error 1
```

I found a situation that is very similar to mine:[perf: util/annotate.c:1752:9: error: too few arguments to function 'init_disassemble_info'](https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/CA+G9fYsd0DaBtWk5cFxPhfM_cZRMQk3MbaxMRN3WJ-yNjAkp7Q@mail.gmail.com/t/)

The solution:

```
This include is guarded by:
#if defined(HAVE_LIBBFD_SUPPORT) && defined(HAVE_LIBBPF_SUPPORT)

and from the header path in the failure you are getting an installed
version of libbfd from /usr/include. Using libbfd (GPLv3) with perf
(GPLv2) is becoming an under tested combination due to:
https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.en.html#v2v3Compatibility
Add the make flag NO_LIBBFD=1 to test without libbfd, which will most
accurately match what distributions build.

Testing on my own machine with libbfd version 2.38 didn't show any failures.
```

So I tried `make NO_LIBBFD=1`, Unfortunately, I received the same error report.
Then I checked libbfd version，it is 2.30 (which is Ubuntu18.04  default ).

Answer (score 0):

Using Intel VTune Profiler to sample more hardware counter information than encapsulated in perf is a good alternative solution.And can try the methods in [this](https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/446319798) article, I almost always succeed. This is the method of compiling perf from source code, and most of the failures are due to incomplete installation of dependencies. I hope it can help people with the same problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: ...especially on non-x86, heh; a good comment but definitely not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

For those who still may bump into this: binutils 2.39 [changed the signature of init_disassemble_info(), which now causes perf and bpftool to fail to compile](http://lore.kernel.org/lkml/20220801013834.156015-1-andres@anarazel.de/) (see also "Thread overview" section).